# Splitting Pundit policies into sub folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I have 2 parts to my application one for an API and then the normal Web application. Each have separate controllers, the API returns json and Web returns views

I am using Pundit for authorization and I would like to place my policies into sub folders like the following

```
>policies    
   >api
   >web
```

When I do this I get

> Pundit::NotDefinedError (unable to find policy `UserPolicy` for

Is there a way of splitting the policies folder into subfolders or is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: Is your `config.autoload_paths` configured to load deeply nested policies? Are you namespacing your policies like `Api::UserPolicy` and `Web::UserPolicy` ? How are you trying to authorize a user?

Comment: Do you really need to namespace policies? Do you have situations where a particular type of user is allowed to perform an action via web and not via api?

Comment: You may try a solution offered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788695/pundit-policies-with-namespaces?rq=1).

Comment: Having the same issue.  I'll post back if I can figure this out...